# Ito's lemma applied to natural log - why is the chain rule not applied to the derivative with respect to time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

It has been a while since I studied stochastic calculus but I have encountered a problem (unrelated to options pricing) at work which requires me to brush up on it.

Looking at [this pdf document](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~nchristo/statistics_c183_c283/statc183c283_ito_black_scholes), we see in section B that $G$ is a function of $S$ only. But $S$ follows a Wiener process, which means it is a function of $t$, so therefore $G$ must also be a function of $t$, no?

The process for $S$ typically looks like $$dS = \mu S dt+\sigma S dz$$
so why (in the link above) is $\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}=0$? Should it not be $\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}$?

Comment: Not a proper answer, but notice that since almost all paths of the Wiener process are nowhere differentiable the expression $\frac{dG}{dt}=G'(S(t))\cdot S'(t)$ does not make any sense.

Comment: @RScrlli actually I think that serves just fine as an answer. An expansion of this answer can be found at https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10861/how-can-the-wiener-process-be-nowhere-differentiable-but-still-continuous

Comment: I advice you to take a look at chapter 7. from "Introduction to stochastic integration" by Kuo. Notice that your idea come from an application of the Newton-Leibniz calculus, but in this framework those rules do not apply, that's precisely the important point of Ito's lemma.

Answer (score 1):

The referenced example is confusing: "$G$ is only a function of $S$". $G$ is a new process with nowhere differentiable trajectories. Formally, $G_t=f(t,S_t)$, where $f(t,x)=\ln(x)$. Itô's lemma is applied to $f$ for which $\partial f/\partial t=0$.